# One object accessible across all my application classes

Tags: c++

I would like to have an object accessible across all my application classes. So I though:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(){}
    int id(){return -1;}
};

extern const MyClass myClass;

int main() {
    cout << myClass.id();
    return 0;
}
```

And anywhere I need it, I'll do:

extern const MyClass myClass;

and just use it, like:

```
cout << myClass.id();
```

But, I was wrong. That returns error:

```
error: passing 'const MyClass' as 'this' argument of 'int MyClass::id()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I Guess I could do `static MyClass myClass;`, instead. And so I will have more or less the same functionality.

What's the best/correct approach?

Comment: `int id() const { return -1; }`

Comment: The error message says that you are calling non-const method `id()` on const object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either discard the `const` in the declaration and definition:

```
extern /* const */ MyClass myClass;
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or make the `id()` function `const`:

```
int id() const {return -1;}
      // ^^^^^
```

> I Guess I could do static MyClass myClass;, instead. And so I will have more or less the same functionality.

A `static` variable would make only sense as a class member.

> What's the best/correct approach?

If you want to ensure that there exists only one instance of the class better use the *Singleton Pattern*:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(){}
public:
    static Myclass& instance() {
        static MyClass theInstance;
        return theInstance;
    }
    int id(){return -1;}
};
```

So you can access the single class instance from everywhere using e.g. `MyClass::instance().id()`, and forbid construction of other instances.

Comment: Making method `const` compiler says `undefined reference to myClass`.

Comment: @KcFnMi You forgot to provide a definition for the global `myClass` variable in another file.